# Как создать свою группу пользователей своими правами?

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно найти выход из следующей ситуации, Мне нужно создать пользователя в правами Админа в точь точь, только это админ не должен удалять главного админа, и не изменять данные.

Есть админ главный ADMIN_ROOT, этот админ может всех удалять и изменять данные.
Есть такой же админ, ADMIN_CHILDREN не может удалить только главного админа изменять данные.

Задача не очень логина ) Но мне этот нужно сделать.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего повесить событие на удаление пользователя и проверять кого удаляют

```
<?
AddEventHandler("main", "OnBeforeUserDelete", Array("MyClass", "OnBeforeUserDeleteHandler"));
class MyClass
{
    function OnBeforeUserDeleteHandler($user_id)
    {
        if ($user_id == 1) 
        {
            // запретим удаление пользователя
            global $APPLICATION;
            $APPLICATION->throwException("Ошибка");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: А можно запретить другим админам изменять логин и пароль и email ГЛАВНОГО АДМИН под идентификатором 1 ?

Comment: Да, так же только событие OnBeforeUserUpdate

Comment: Спасибо дружище, Ты дал показал свет в конце туннеля )

Answer (score -1):

Ребята нашел выход из ситуации, может кому то пригодиться. 
Под главном админом не могут авторизоваться, и изменять данные. 
Прописал в init.php у меня не было этого файла. Сам создал. Файл должен находится по адресу Bitrix/php_interface/init.php

```
 <?
AddEventHandler("main", "OnBeforeProlog", Array("MyClass", "limitRootAdminManipulations"));

use \Bitrix\Main\Context;

class MyClass
{
    function limitRootAdminManipulations()
    {
        global $APPLICATION;
        global $USER;

        $request = Context::getCurrent()->getRequest();
        $user_id = $request->get("ID");

        if($APPLICATION->GetCurPage() == '/bitrix/admin/user_edit.php')
        {
            if ($user_id == 1 && $USER->GetID() != 1)
                die("Error! You cannot change root admin data. Ошибка! Вы не можете изменить данные root администратора");
        }

        if($APPLICATION->GetCurPage() == '/bitrix/admin/user_admin.php')
        {
            if ($user_id == 1 && $USER->GetID() != 1)
                die("Error! You cannot auth as root admin. Ошибка! Вы не можете авторизоваться от root администратора");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: А удалить получается можно

Comment: На самом такое стремноватое решение и скорее похоже на ворота посреди поля. Если права администратора полностью дублируются точь в точь, то никто не мешает выполнить SQL код на странице по смене данных админа к таблице b_user (например сменить сумму пароля рутового админа на сумму своего пароля и зайти под админом), ну или поменять напрямую данные, да хотя бы через интерфейс /bitrix/admin/perfmon_table.php?lang=ru&table_name=b_user. Тут по другому подходить к разграничению прав нужно.

Comment: Причем сам Битрикс позволяет одной группе запретить редактировать другую группу пользователей, а с остальными делать что угодно.